# Determining if Polygon Contains Negative Space using ArcGIS SOAP Web Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, polygon, soap, donut-polygons

I am running queries against a polygon layer using the ArcGIS SOAP Web Service.  A user selects a point within that layer and the resulting feature set contains PolygonN objects.

Occasionally, the polygons that come back contain negative space.  These are also known as donut or [island polygons](http://kb.iu.edu/data/ancm.html).  Here is an example:

[image]

In this case, I would only want the geometry contained in the purple area, not the green area.

When the user selects a point within the purple area, the resulting [PolygonN](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/soap/SOAP_PolygonN.htm) object contains 2 [rings](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/soap/SOAP_Ring.htm), representing the outer and inner areas, as it should.

The inner ring, as far as I can tell, has no way to indicate that it is actually negative space.  So the resulting polygon looks like it has 2 solid shapes, when in fact it is only one shape with a hole in the center.

Does anyone know how I can determine that a polygon's ring is actually negative space?

Comment: Is the [area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid) of the inner ring negative while that of the outer ring is positive?

Comment: The inner ring does not contain an Area attribute.  From the API's perspective it is just a path where the first and last points are the same.           http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/soap/SOAP_Ring.htm

Comment: Right, you'll need to use the [formula at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid) to step through the points and compute area.  A clockwise ring should have positive area while a counterclockwise has negative.  Standard practice is to have negative area (counterclockwise) rings to represent interior rings.

Comment: That worked.  If you add that to the Answer section, I'll check it off.   Thanks Kirk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common practice to represent islands as *counterclockwise* rings with exterior rings as *clockwise*.  If you use [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid) to calculate area by stepping through the points in each ring, you should see positive area for the exterior ring, but negative area for the interior one.

[image: area formula]